# Webservice returns an ad page instead of data in monodroid app

Tags: php, web-services, xamarin.android, httpwebresponse

I have been testing an app i am writing in Monodroid(Mono for android). Basically i am storing some simple data to the database via a php post 
(http:// [my-domain]/register_php?/usrname=blabla&usremail=blabla)
(I am using thre free web hosting service 000webhost.com.)

The php page sends back a response a simple string if it has succeded

```
<?php
         (...)
      if( $success )
      {
          echo "Success";
      }else{
          echo "Failure";
      }
   >
```

But in my android app I don't receive this simple string back as the answer. Rather I receive a full html page advertising the services 000webhost.com offers. **But if i enter the url into my chrome browser every thing works fine and I receive the appropriate status (weither it has succeeded or not)**

Here is the code to post data:

```
byte[] post_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("name={0}&email=
{1}",txt_usr_name.Text,txt_usr_email .Text) );
HttpWebRequest wb_request = 
(HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create("http://[my-domain]/register_user.php" );
wb_request.Method = "POST";
wb_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
wb_request.ContentLength = post_data.Length;

Stream stream = wb_request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write( post_data, 0, post_data.Length );
stream.Close();
```

And here is the code to read back the response:

```
    HttpWebResponse wb_response = ( HttpWebResponse )wb_request.GetResponse();

    string status_code = wb_response.StatusCode.ToString();
    string server = wb_response.Server.ToString();

    Stream answer = wb_response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader ans_reader = new StreamReader( answer );

    string result = ans_reader.ReadToEnd();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    builder.SetTitle( "Connection result" );
    builder.SetMessage( result );
    builder.SetPositiveButton( "OK", delegate { } );
    var dialog = builder.Create();
    dialog.Show();
```

Is there something I am forgetting to set when i call the webservice? 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would **guess** that your free web service is putting some other filter in place before your PHP page.

It may be using HTTP headers like accept or user-agent to determine whether or not to use your PHP.

Try using the Request Builder (now called Composer) within the excellent Fiddler2 tool to create HTTP requests - within a few minutes you will find out which headers you need to send.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/